# Trouble gunzipping .gz files on MacOS

Tags: macos, zlib, gunzip

Eurostat european database provides a lot of gzipped files such as https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/BulkDownloadListing?file=data/env_air_gge.tsv.gz

When I download such files and then double-click on them, they are correctly unzipped by the Archive Utility on MacOS. But when I try to use gunzip on MacOS Terminal the destination file is gunzipped as a... gz file (without the extension).

I tried to use [GZIP API](https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP) in a custom Objective-C application (and a custom deflating function designed using zlib): both gives the same result as does gunzip in the Terminal application. On the contrary, using the same C deflating function in a Linux program works perfectly on those gzipped files.

What could be the trouble with zlib library and command line gunzip on MacOS that prevent them from treating correctly some gz files? This problem that has apparently be overcome by the Archive Utility Application included with MacOS...

[**UPDATE**] This becomes more strange: When I get the gz file from another source (for example https://github.com/dhalperi/cse550-code-data/raw/master/density-peaks/rawdata/sample.csv.gz), everything is OK. So the problem lays in the Eurostat website + MacOS combination!

[[**UPDATE**]] Solution found:

• in the http response from Eurostat, Content-Type is defined as "application/octet-stream" (and encoding defined as "gzip").

• With this setting, the server gzip the file on the fly, so that it is twice gzipped

• When Content-Type is defined as "application/x-gzip" the server do not gzip it, and the file can be decompressed in one pass...

• Analysis of the server response allows to detect twice gzipped files to know when two unzip are necessary.

Comment: What command did you use to unpack the zip?

Comment: It's not a zip but a gzip. As I explained, I used GZIP API, a custom C routine and the MacOS Terminal's gunzip program. Both fails to expand the gz. On a Linux PC, there is no problem. And on MacOS with other gz sources, there is no problem. It occurs only with Eurostat's gzipped files on MacOS

Comment: `gunzip env_air_gge.tsv.gz` worked fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

Seems fine to me. How did you download it? What is the size of the file after downloading? I get 2,989,400 bytes.

From the comments, yours is larger. It may have been gzipped multiple times. Archive Utility will keep gunzipping it until it no longer has a gzip header. You would have to do that yourself with the command-line gunzip.

Comment: The download is made with a NSURLSession and dataTaskWithURL method. This process do not decompress silently: the downloaded gz file is 3MB. After using gunzip or several gzip APIs it is still ~3MB, with a gzip header. Using Archive Utility provided by MacOS, il expands to 12,4MB…

Comment: I used gunzip in macOS terminal, no problem. On both of the files you linked. (Which, by the way, are different files, not the same file.)

Comment: What is the exact size of the downloaded ~3MB file, and what are the first ten bytes?

Comment: The downloaded file size is 2 997 731 Bytes. The first bytes are: \x1f\x8b\b

Comment: When I download it, it's 2,989,400 bytes. You seem to be getting some extra cruft somehow.

Comment: Maybe it's getting another gzip wrapper around it from the http server. What is the exact size after decompressing? Did you try putting a .gz on the result of decompressing, and trying to decompress it again?

Comment: After decompressing, it’s 2,997,540 bytes. I tried everything! After adding .gz gunzip do not decompress, but Archive Utility does...

Comment: It got smaller. gunzip it again.

Comment: I gunzipped ten times in a row... nothing. I just made an experiment. When I download another file on Eurostat with Safari, I have the same problem with the it (1,487,149 bytes). When I download it using Firefox (1,482,889 bytes), gunzip works perfectly on it! And this time, after Safari downloaded, running gunzip gives the same size as gzip obtained with Firefox. And running a second time gunzip works! 
So: depending on the file, a Safari download does not give the same result, I hate these instabilities!

Comment: I found the problem: in the http response from Eurostat, Content-Type is defined as "application/octet-stream" (and encoding defined as "gzip"). So the server gzip the file on the fly, so that it is twice gzipped (I do not understand why I could try ungzip 10 times in a row on a file, probably it was corrupted)...
When Content-Type is defined as "application/x-gzip" the server do not gzip it, and the file can be decompressed in one pass...
Saying that, I can now check the response information to check wether a file has been gzipped twice or not and manage it! Thanks for help, Mark